# Refactoring Google Sheets to generic database interface

Tags: c#, .net, database-design, interface

I've written some classes in .NET to handle Google Sheets functionality, and I'm trying to refactor it to a generic database interface. Here's the gist of what I've written.

```
public class GoogleSheet { // Represents Google Sheet document
    public Dictionary<string, GoogleSheetSpreadSheet> Spreadsheets { get; set; } // Individual spreadsheets
    private SheetsService service; // Google sheet service
    public void SendData() // Sends edited spreadsheet data to document
    public void RetrieveData() // Retrieves sheet data from the web
}

public class GoogleSheetSpreadsheet { // Represents individual spreadsheet
    public List<GoogleSheetRow> Values { get; private set; } // Rows
    public OrderedDictionary<string, int> Headers { get; private set; } // Headers of rows (column names)
    public void SendData() // Sends edited spreadsheet data to document
    public void RetrieveData() // Retrieves sheet data from the web
}

public class GoogleSheetRow {
    public OrderedDictionary<string, GoogleSheetCell> Cells { get; set; } // Individual cells in row
}

public class GoogleSheetCell {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    // And then some other GoogleSheet specific cell formatting
}
```

It kind of works like a 3D matrix, which you can index via keys as well.

My idea was to use generics in an interface, sort of like this:

```
public interface IDatabase<T> where T: IDatabaseTable<IDatabaseRow<IDatabaseCell>>; // Implemented by GoogleSheet
public interface IDatabaseTable<T> where T: IDatabaseRow<IDatabaseCell>; // Implemented by GoogleSheetSpreadsheet
public interface IDatabaseRow<T> where T: IDatabaseCell; // Implemented by GoogleSheetRow
public interface IDatabaseCell // Implemented by GoogleSheetCell
```

But then I get variance issues when I try implementing the interfaces.

```
public class GoogleSheet : IDatabase<GoogleSheetSpreadSheet> // introduces variance issues - Can't implicitly convert.
```

Using the `out` keyword didn't work either.

```
public interface IDatabaseTable<out T> where T : IDatabaseRow<IDatabaseCell>
{
    List<out T> Rows { get; } 
    // invalid variance: the type parameter T must be invariantly valid on Rows. T is covariant
    // Invalid variance modifier. Only interfaces and delegates can be specified as variant
}
```

I'm not very familiar with generics so I am probably abusing them greatly here.

I think the problem here is that tables, rows, and cells are all really tightly coupled - A GoogleSheetSpreadsheet MUST contain GoogleSheetRows, which MUST contain GoogleSheetCells. Each implementation of an interface is coupled to other specific implementations of an interface.

I've been working on this for a bit so I think I can't see the forest for the trees at this point. Is there a good way to achieve what I want to do (basically interfaces with nested generics), and if not, how can I redesign my base classes to decouple them?

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Chetan sure. When using the out keyword, I get `invalid variance: the type parameter T must be invariantly valid on Rows. T is covariant`, and `invalid variance modifier: only interface and delegate modifiers can be specified as variant`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my problem. I used a repository interface, then made database , tables, and row interfaces that subclass the repository.

Starting from the bottom up:

```
public interface IRepository<TKey, TEntry>
{
    OrderedDictionary<TKey, TEntry> Items { get; set; }

    ICollection<TKey> Keys { get; }
    ICollection<TEntry> Values { get; }

    TEntry this[TKey key] { get; }
}

public interface IDatabaseRow<TCellKey, TEntry> : IRepository<TCellKey, TEntry>
{
}

public interface IDatabaseTable<TRowKey, TCellKey, TEntry> : IRepository<TRowKey, IDatabaseRow<TCellKey, TEntry>>
{
    OrderedDictionary<TRowKey, IDatabaseRow<TCellKey, TEntry>> RetrieveData();

    void SendData();
}

public interface IDatabase<TTableKey, TRowKey, TCellKey, TCell> : IRepository<TTableKey, IDatabaseTable<TRowKey, TCellKey, TCell>>
{
}
```

When you want to implement the database interface, you just provide your keys, and the entry type.

```
public class GoogleSheet : IDatabase<string, int, string, GoogleSheetCell>
```

I don't know how "proper" this solution is, but I was able to integrate this into my existing code fairly easily.